# HLS stream ended callback using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming, wowza

I'm using wowza to play a live stream with HLS. Now for example if someone is viewing a live stream and the person who's live stream is being viewed stops it, the live stream on the viewers end should stop as well without having to refresh the list.

What i have tried is setting up observers to observe state changes for buffer and video stopped playing etc.

```
func addMyObservers() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoStopped(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self)

    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .new, context: nil)
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: .new, context: nil)
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: .new, context: nil)
}
```

Now i get callbacks for `playBackBufferEmpty` if the stream has been stopped by the streamer on user end but not for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`, which i guess is understandable.

One possible solution is using push notifications but I would like to avoid that(as there is no guarantee of them being received) and another one is creating a socket connection on the backend which is also not possible.

Does anyone have any idea on how i can go about implementing that the viewer UI automatically updates when streamer stops recording or the live stream ends?

Comment: Last time I had a discussion with Wowza and they suggested several ways of determining when a stream is really finished. One of them was to put a check on `statusCode`. If it's 404, then streaming has been ended.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan since i'm directly playing the url from the m3u8 file in AVPlayer, how will it be possible to determine what `statusCode` i get? If you had a discussion on their forums, i would appreciate a link so that i can go through it myself!

Comment: I'm afraid it was exchange of emails with their technical team. Even if you talk to them about it, they'd mention this as one of the solution. Trick is to make a simple GET request to your *.m3u8 URL. However, there were other solutions as well so it's better you directly talk to them first.

Comment: My app have live streaming in m3u8 format, but could not get the end notification. Did any of you guys have the solution for it?

Comment: @Hamed we ended up using sockets to get real time updates of video ending. But owing to the delay some ending part **does** get clipped.